# ein Recht auf oder an etwas?

Tags: preposition

I know that "Recht auf frische Luft" is correct, but can the word "Recht" also be used with the preposition "an", and if so, in what situations? Would it also be correct to say "Recht an frischer Luft?" Thank you.

Comment: It's getting really funny with "Anrecht auf"... not that I could construct a sentence with it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it can, but it changes the meaning: Recht *an* means that you own or possess something and are exercising this right.

Examples:

> Der Erfinder besitzt ein Recht an seiner Erfindung. 
>   Ein Recht an einer Liegenschaft darf im Grundbuch nur eingetragen werden, wenn ...